# Change AndroidManifest.xml to set LAUNCHER activity base on shared preference

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have a registration activity and also a main activity.

**What I want to achieve:**

I want to:

1) show the registration activity if the user hasn't registered

2) show the main activity if the user has registered

What I did:

1) I have changed the registration activity to be the Main/Launcher activity in the Android.Manifest.xml file:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".RegistrationActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**Problem:**

1) How do I set the Main Activity as the Launcher activity after the the Register Button is pressed for subsequent app launches?

```
public void btnRegisterPressed (View view) {

        // Save isRegistered flag into Shared Preferences
        SharedPreferences userDetails = this.getSharedPreferences("userDetails", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = userDetails.edit();
        edit.clear();
        edit.putBoolean("isRegistered", true);

        Intent i = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: use a splash or launcher screen

Comment: Hi @r7v, is it possible to use a splash screen? my registration activity has a few activities as well, enter user name and password activity, enter other details activity (this is where the btnRegisterPressed resides)

Comment: Thanks @Heyyou, please help.

Comment: You cannot dynamically change the launcher screen . Have an activity  (Splash/Launcher) as the launcher activity, and do the logic on the onCreate() of the activity .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to make a landing page for the app and have the method run in it, if you don't want them to land into the current main. So the `run` method is the one to go to main.

I prefer to keep my shared preferences as constants for my app.

```
pref = getSharedPreferences(MyConstants.MY_APP);
    editor = pref.edit();



public void run(View view) {
    String getStatus = pref.getString(MyConstants.REGISTER, "nil");
    if (getStatus.equals("true")) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Main.class));
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Register first",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

In your register class:

```
editor.putString(MyConstants.REGISTER, "true");
    editor.commit();
```